# Desabilitar o migrate do Flyway no startup e executar só quando requisitado

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Estou iniciando a pouco tempo com o `Flyway` no `Java` junto com o `Spring Boot` e atualmente tenho uma atividade que diz para mim fazer o `Flyway` executar o `migrate()` apenas quando um certo endpoint for executado e com as propriedades do banco de dados(Url, user, password) que for mandado.

O problema é, o `Flyway` atualmente esta executando o `migrate()` quando o projeto dá startup e com as propriedades de `datasource` que eu especificar no arquivo `application.properties`, eu dei uma olhada nos docs do `Spring Boot` e vi que da pra criar uma classe que implementa o `FlywayMigrationStrategy` que me da um controle maior sobre o `Flyway` mas ainda não é oque eu quero, ainda não consigo, por exemplo, chamar um método passando um parâmetro para especificar o `datasource` do banco de dados e esse método executar o `migrate()` com o `datasource` que eu passei por parâmetro.

Já procurei em muitos lugares, docs do Spring Boot e do Flyway por exemplo, mas não consegui achar a resposta, alguém pode me dar uma luz?

edit 1:

Eu consegui executar o `migrate()` criando uma variável do tipo `ClassicConfiguration` e setando o `datasource` nela e depois usando o construtor do objeto `Flyway` passando o `ClassicConfiguration` como parâmetro e passando esse objeto `Flyway` como parâmetro para o `migrate()`.

Só que eu estou com um problema que não consigo executar o meu projeto `Spring Boot` sem um `datasource` configurado, por uma classe `@Configuration` do `Java` ou pelo arquivo `application.properties`.

A intenção é que ele execute o projeto e faça o `migrate()` somente quando um endpoint especifico for executado(o endpoint em questão executaria o `migrate()` com os parâmetros para conexão com o banco de dados do próprio endpoint), e assim logo em seguida guarde o `datasource` que foi usado no `migrate()` na sessão para que o mesmo usuário possa fazer outras requisições sem problemas. Seria uma aplicação `multi-tenacy`.

Answer (score 1):

Para desabilitar o Flyway durante o startup você pode incluir o seguinte parâmetro no seu `application.properties`:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

Isso já vai desabilitar a autoconfiguração do Flyway

---

### Edit :)

Você pode criar um *wrapper* e montar as configurações do Flyway na mão:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationStrategy;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

public class FlywayMigrationWrapper {

    private final Flyway flyway;

    public MyFlywayMigrationStrategy(String url, String username, String password) {           
        this.flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(buildDatasource()).load();
    }

    private DataSource buildDatasource(String url, String username, String password) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url).username(username).password(password).build();
    }

    public void migrate(Flyway flyway) {
        flyway.clean();
        flyway.migrate();
    }
}
```

Não cheguei a rodar esse código, nem jogar na IDE, peguei alguns exemplos da API do Flyway e da API do Spring Boot (nem sei se o código compila).

Você pode então criar um `@Bean` e injetá-lo onde for necessário, ou customizar mais :)

Sugiro dar uma lida na API do [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc.html) para mais informações.

Comment: certo amigo, funcionou, mas e agora, como chamo o método `migrate()` passando o `datasource` por parâmetro?

Comment: Você quer executar o migration passando quais parâmetros?

Comment: os parâmetros de um objeto `Datasource`
- Url
- Senha
- User

Comment: @BrunoEduardo editei a resposta

Comment: Certo amigo, eu acho que entendi e vou tentar fazer isto amanha porque agora estou sem tempo, mas assim, eu consegui fazer algo parecido(ate editei a pergunta explicando isso la em cima) só que eu tive alguns problemas, não consegui executar o projeto sem um datasource inicial configurado, até consegui executar o `migrate()` pelo endpoint porem a próxima requisição que eu faço que precisa fazer uma conexão com o banco da erro dizendo que o `datasource` não esta configurado, se puder me ajudar com isso eu agradeceria muito amigo.

Comment: Para subir o projeto sem datasource você precisa desabilitar o autoconfiguration, mas isso já é assunto para outra pergunta :) acho que sua pergunta original foi atendida apenas com o `spring.flyway.enabled=false`

Comment: na verdade ela foi respondida em partes, digamos que não adianta eu conseguir executar o projeto sem que o flyway execute o migrate() se o projeto não executa, e também eu ja vi uma pergunta assim aqui no stackoverflow mesmo sobre desabilitar o autoconfiguration usando o exclude para não executar a classe de AutoConfiguration do datasource, só que fazendo isso da um erro no JdbcTemplate que eu uso aqui, mas tenho que pesquisar melhor sobre isso

Comment: mas mesmo assim valeu por me dar um norte amigo